# in sql server 2008 r2, join two column without create a table

Tags: sql

I have to concat two column without creating a table in 2008's r2. Is that possible?

eg. `select concat ('a', 'b');`

This query working in the 2012 version, how can I write this query in 2008's r2?

Comment: Have you tried `select 'a' + 'b'`?

Comment: Yeah got. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this:**
SELECT (a + '-' + b) AS a_b from TableName

Comment: Thanks for your response.